# In PHP 5.x, how can I detect if a class is abstract or not at run time?

Tags: php, oop, reflection

I'm looping through an array of class names in PHP, fetched via get_declared_classes().

How can I check each class name to detect whether or not that particular class is an abstract class or not?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use reflection. [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/ReflectionClass)`->isAbstract()`

Use it like this:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('NameOfTheClass');
$abstract = $class->isAbstract();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it *without* using ReflectionClass (so that I don't need to implement the ReflectionClass methods?)

Comment: you just pass the name of your class to ReflectionClass constructor

Comment: Ah, yes I see that now. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Note that if you are testing the abstractness in order to decide whether it is instantiable or not, you may need to use [`isInstantiable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isinstantiable.php), which checks for abstract classes, interfaces, private constructors etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.reflection.php#language.oop5.reflection.reflectionclass) on the class.

Comment: hah, I upvoted you, too.  Damn, had to keep that brief to try to get first, but you win :)

Comment: Better to provide a complete answer than a quick one.  This is too brief to really answer the question.  Did you know that you get a badge if you delete one of your own questions that has received a few upvotes? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 

abstract class Picasso
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
} 

$class = new ReflectionClass('Picasso');

if($class->isAbstract())
{
    echo "Im abstract";
}
else
{
    echo "Im not abstract";
}

?>
```

See the manual : www.php.net/oop5.reflection